# Unable to start a nested transaction for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server

I have two linked servers and want to create a stored procedure that simply `SELECT`s data from one table from the first server and `INSERT` the data in other table from the second server.

The procedure code looks like this:

```
BEGIN TRAN

INSERT INTO [RI].[TEST_DB].[TEST_TABLE] (...)
SELECT ...
FROM [TABLE]

TRUNCATE [TABLE]

COMMIT TRAN
```

But I get the following error:

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "RI" returned message "Cannot start more transactions on this session.".
>   Msg 7395, Level 16, State 2, Procedure usp_test, Line 46
>   Unable to start a nested transaction for OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "RI".
>   A nested transaction was required because the XACT_ABORT option was set to OFF.

Answer (score 6):

As the error message suggests, add the following to your stored procedure:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
```

See [Distributed Queries and Distributed Transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177403(v=sql.105).aspx)